# app.control.revoke() doesn't change the state in CELERY, python

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have this conditional:

```py
lst_of_active_tasks = insp.active()
        print(lst_of_active_tasks)
        for task in lst_of_active_tasks["celery@DESKTOP-HM2VGD6"]:
            if task["args"] and task["args"][0] == psid:
                app.control.revoke(task["id"])
```

checking if the task already exists and being processed by a worker. Then:

```py
process_and_send_message.apply_async(args=[psid, 
                                           page.facebook_page_id,
                                           page.facebook_papge_token,
                                           conversation_dict])
```

which should send this task to be processed by a worker:

```py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def process_and_send_message(self,psid, page_id, page_token, conversation_dict):
    for _ in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        result = AsyncResult(self.request.id)
        if result.state == "REVOKED":
            print("REVOKED")
            return "REVOKED"
        print(f"{result.id} :::::::::>>>>>>>  {result.state}")

    
    return("some text")
```

I want the task to return REVOKED if the task state is revoked.
Problem is even after it being flagged as REVOKED it still gets processed:

```
[2024-02-25 09:34:59,652: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2024-02-25 09:35:00,659: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2024-02-25 09:35:00,670: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-HM2VGD6 ready.
[2024-02-25 09:35:05,584: INFO/MainProcess] Task apis.tasks.process_and_send_message[13652c4a-9ec3-438e-946d-3b1d91ee592a] received
[2024-02-25 09:35:06,588: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 13652c4a-9ec3-438e-946d-3b1d91ee592a :::::::::>>>>>>>  PENDING
[2024-02-25 09:35:07,592: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 13652c4a-9ec3-438e-946d-3b1d91ee592a :::::::::>>>>>>>  PENDING
[2024-02-25 09:35:08,594: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 13652c4a-9ec3-438e-946d-3b1d91ee592a :::::::::>>>>>>>  PENDING
[2024-02-25 09:35:08,703: INFO/MainProcess] Tasks flagged as revoked: 13652c4a-9ec3-438e-946d-3b1d91ee592a
[2024-02-25 09:35:08,707: INFO/MainProcess] Task apis.tasks.process_and_send_message[bbbbfcea-0680-4f7b-9f4c-dd37ec291e89] received
[2024-02-25 09:35:09,597: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 13652c4a-9ec3-438e-946d-3b1d91ee592a :::::::::>>>>>>>  PENDING
[2024-02-25 09:35:09,716: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] bbbbfcea-0680-4f7b-9f4c-dd37ec291e89 :::::::::>>>>>>>  PENDING
[2024-02-25 09:35:10,600: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 13652c4a-9ec3-438e-946d-3b1d91ee592a :::::::::>>>>>>>  PENDING
[2024-02-25 09:35:10,719: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] bbbbfcea-0680-4f7b-9f4c-dd37ec291e89 :::::::::>>>>>>>  PENDING
```

I tried:

- `app.conf.worker_pool_restarts = True`  >>>> didn't work
- `app.control.revoke(task["id"], terminate=True)` >>>> terminate causes the whole worker to stop. and I'm afraid if the worker stops. other tasks will be dropped too. I want just that specific task to drop.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?